# convert numeric array to associative using another array for keys

Tags: php

I have a csv table, with the first row as the header. I would like to iterate through all the rows, using the name of the column to refer to the column instead of its numerical value. To do this, I think as I iterate I need to convert each numerically indexed row into an associative one, but I can't figure out the best way to do this.

```
$headerrow = str_getcsv($table[0]); //gives me an array like 0=>foo,1=>bar,2=>bat
foreach ($table as $rownumber=>$row){
    if($rownumber!=0){
        $rowarray=str_getcsv($row);//gives me an array like 0=>blah,1=>blah,2=>blah
        //how do I get $rowarray['foo'] or $rowarray['bar'] most efficiently?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess I should have looked more closely at the array functions. I found array_combine.

```
$rowarray = array_combine($headerrow,str_getcsv($row));
print($rowarray['foo']);
```

Comment: Exactomundo.  `$combined = array_combine($keys, $values)`